# Webpack 2: Build Multi-Part Library and Use as an External

Tags: webpack

I'm using Webpack 2 and trying to bundle a common library that will be used in several of my company's projects. Dependencies include vue, vue-router, and some others. It seems to make sense to package these vendor dependencies into a single common file, and then include that as an external by the various projects. However I can't seem to get this to work.

My library webpack.config.js includes lines:

```
entry: {
    common: [
        'vue',
        'vue-router'
    ]
}
...
output: {
    filename: '[name].js',
    libraryTarget: 'var'
}
```

My consuming project's webpack.config.js includes:

```
externals: {
    'vue': 'Vue',
    'vue-router': 'VueRouter'
}
```

I've tried setting `output.library` on common to `common` and the extern to, for example, `['common','Vue']`. This doesn't work.

I've tried setting `libraryTarget` on both the library and consumer to `"amd"`, and that just results in `define` being undefined. If I use `"var"`, things only work if I only wrap one library in `common`, if I wrap more than one then both are undefined.

Is what I'm trying to do possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you need to use externals (as above) and that's all.

And then you can get your external dependencies in "es5 way" as script tag (e.g. https://unpkg.com/vue@2.2.6/dist/vue.runtime.min.js) or from npm and just use it. Or save it into *.js file if you need.

Webpack create bundle wich may get dependency from module (e.g. es 2015) or from global variable (es5).

So bundles for external libs is already exists in npm.